# AS3 - Get Context menu selection

Tags: actionscript-3

How to find out which menu item was selected?

```
cm1.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT,changeColor);
cm2.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT,changeColor);

function changeColor(event:ContextMenuEvent):void{
trace("cm1 or cm2?")
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function changeColor(event:ContextMenuEvent):void{
  if(event.target == cm1){
    //Do something
  } else if(event.target == cm2){
    //Do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trace the event target to find out the current target (that was clicked)

```
function changeColor(event:ContextMenuEvent):void{
trace(event.currentTarget);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, add separate listeners to each context menu element:

cm1.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, changeColorCM1);
cm2.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT,changeColorCM2);

function changeColorCM1(event:ContextMenuEvent):void{ //CM1 }

function changeColorCM2(event:ContextMenuEvent):void{ //CM2 }